# make: Nothing to be done for `all'. on Target That Just Calls Another Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Say I have the following gnu makefile.

```
TOP := $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))

all : graphics

graphics :
  pushd $(TOP)../graphics; \
  $(TOP)../tools/autotools_gen.sh; \
  ./configure; \
  $(MAKE) clean all; \
  $(TOP)../tools/autotools_clr.sh; \
  popd;
```

inside a folder called build and I call it from one directory up, in the following manner:

```
make --file ./build/Makefile all
```

and I get the following message from make:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

Why is it complaining that there is nothing to be done for all?

Comment: Do you have a file or directory named `all`?  Note you should not use `pushd` or `popd` as they're not available in POSIX `sh`, plus you don't need them since each recipe logical line is started in its own shell.

Comment: no I do not have a directory called all. I do have a directory called graphics. Perhaps rename graphics to something else?

Comment: If `graphics` already exists, then what do you want Make to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you run into is that because you have a directory `graphics` (I took this from the question comments) in the working directory, when make encounters the target

```
graphics :
```

as a prerequisite for `all`, it sees that `graphics` already exists, that none of its prerequisites are newer than it (because it doesn't have any), and so considers it up to date and does nothing to build it. Since `all` doesn't have a recipe of its own, make then doesn't find anything to do for it either and just tells you that there's nothing to do.

The solution is to declare `graphics` and `all` as phony targets:

```
.PHONY: all graphics
```

Then they will be run even if files or directories called `all` or `graphics` exist/are newer than their dependencies.

The intent of phony targets is to make rules that don't produce a file work properly even if such a file accidentally appears in the directory of the Makefile, so it is commonly used for targets `all`, `clean`, `install` and suchlike. Your `graphics` target doesn't produce a file `graphics`, so it falls into this category.

See also [this section](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html) in the GNU make manual (which also applies to other makes).